# Why is a devise cookie not set on XHR request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise, xmlhttprequest, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using devise on a Rails4 app that serves a JSON API. I patched devise, so it accepts an authentication token via HTTP header instead of an URL parameter. That works pretty well.

A JS single page application based on that API works well. I can authenticate a user, and request this users resources inside the app.

In addition I'd like the server (devise) to set a cookie, so that cookie based auth works, and I can request a users private resource through non XHR requests as well. This does not work and I do not know why.

Im my devise initializer I have:

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true
```

In my session_store initializer I set:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', domain: :all, httponly: false, secure: false
```

When I run my single page app inside Chrome and inspect the network requests, I can see that every response to a request of a server side resource includes a `Set-Cookie` Header like so:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Ua-Compatible: chrome=1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * //dont give me shelter
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
X-Meta-Request-Version: 0.2.8
Etag: "7b64cd327b9ff8dce6bb8b616aeee2b8"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: 1d6be45e-ce45-40fd-b03b-358644826955
X-Runtime: 0.283514
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2013-06-27)
Date: Fri, 23 Aug 2013 10:36:04 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: _myapp_session=NndJcUd5QUJmRktkSkdTVTk1NTF3UHVKaW85QkVmTmpqZEM4Q3BqUW5ORzNyNG5HWmlnSWc5Yy83Nk16c3Q0dk1iVXQ0Q2JqTE1qZWZoaDgxNW1RQnErOHhsVG9rdEQ4cU1CNGsyNWsrVlk0OXlLRGo5c1BiN3NkdFlRdWJHVXBDamI1U1BrdlQ3Mmw3OWNZVWJkWGI1UWZqNDJ1VldxL0xvYkkwYVd5aHBYaU5sOElkZ3NSRXZVdGxlWHQxY1FteFh1OGU3NHowYU0xYTRLK2xuTEN4KzhzR2pjR25YWlZVSTZtZDkvUnZXbz0tLXJKMXNlV1gvcHFuaG5jU3YvNUJhSnc9PQ%3D%3D--5ecf40e2a678b467b77aa0c56494be8e079641d2; domain=.myapp.dev; path=/
```

My app is served from `app.myapp.dev` on port 9000 and requests the API at `api.myapp.dev` on port 3000. That works fine due to proper CORS config.

If I have a look inside Chrome's Resource panel under `Cookies` no cookie is set. Since there is no cookie, every non-XHR request to api.myapp.net does not authenticate a user.

I do not understand, why the cookie set header seems fine, but the cookie is not set?

Can anyone enlighten me?

Regards
Felix

Answer (score 5):

Ok, as I found out so far, it is possible to deliver a JS app from `a.domain.com` and let it fetch JSON data from `b.domain.com` with CORS enabled, but cookies sent by `b.domain.com` will not be set. Some kind of evil could go on here.

So the only way to solve the problem in my case is: Let the user login to the JS app, redirect him to an endpoint at `b.domain.com` and add an authentication token. The server at `b` logges the user in, can now set a cookie and redirects the user to the JS app afterwards.

That's a horrible solution, cause the app loads twice then, but as long as you deliver your app from another subdomain than your API there seems to be no better solution. Quite open for any.

**Update**

Setting cross domain cookies is indeed possible in case you are in control of the servers headers.

What solved the problem in my case was:

`b.domain.com` sets an additional response header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to true. In addition inside backbone sync needs to be patched, so that the passed options object gets a key `xhrFields` with `withCredentials:true`. And that was it. When `b.domain.com` responds with a `Set-Cookie` header, the cookie is set, even if the JS app was delivered from `a.domain.com`. Not to forget: When you set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, you can not use a wildcard for Access-Control-Allow-Origin (which you should not anyway).